# ARM64/Android : Compiler use SP instead of X29 as base frame pointer

Tags: assembly, android-ndk, inline-assembly, arm64

I have to push arguments on the stack to pass parameters to functions. However the clang of Android NDK compiler (64 bits), always use `sp` register as base address to reach variables, whereas it should use `x29` (the base frame pointer).

I have `ldr w11, [sp, #0x30]`, I want `ldr w11, [x29, #0x30]`.

This bothers me because, if I inject asm into my c code `sub sp, sp, x9` in order to push argument, I disturb all the reference that was using the older `sp`.

Do you know why it doesn't use `x29`, and if I can force it to do so ?

Until now, my idea was to write arguments below the `sp` pointer without to move it, and when it is done, move `sp` just before calling the function. And just after restore `sp` to its older value.

I'm not so sure that writing data below `sp` is a good idea, what do you thing about it ?

> **Additional information :** There is a notable complication: memory below the architectural sp (but in the stack area) cannot be safely accessed. Notably, this area is used by signal handlers, which execute asynchronously (like interrupts). If we just copy sp to some other register and start using it as a (descending) stack pointer, our special stack area will eventually be corrupted. https://community.arm.com/developer/ip-products/processors/b/processors-ip-blog/posts/using-the-stack-in-aarch64-implementing-push-and-pop

Comment: In optimized code it's common not to use a frame pointer. You can sometimes turn it off using `-fno-omit-frame-pointer` but that's not guaranteed to work. This sounds like an XY problem. You are using assembly wrong if you just inject stuff into compiler generated code.

Comment: Thanks, i thing you're right. I would prefer directly develop in assembly and not inject it into c. The problem is that Android Studio does not provide an assembly debugger, that is why i take the decision to code everything in c and inject assembly only when this is necessary. I've implemented my idea exposed just above, it seems to work now but i'm not very confident.

Comment: Assuming you used "extended" inline asm, did you specify `sp` in the clobber list?